# react-big-calendar with typescript dnd constructor shows error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-big-calendar

I'm trying to work with [react-big-calendar](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar). And this project is based on typescript.

When I try to initialize drag-n-drop with it, it gives me a certain error:

```
const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar)
```

I'm not sure what to do, as their official doc, gives us this example, [here](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/blob/d695d0a51143f83f3ecda35044e53c28d7d39a2a/examples/demos/dnd.js#L8)

The error message says:

```
/home/maifee/Desktop/e/rbc_test/src/components/containers/task-organizer/TaskOrganizer.tsx
TypeScript error in /home/maifee/Desktop/e/rbc_test/src/components/containers/task-organizer/TaskOrganizer.tsx(26,45):
Argument of type 'typeof Calendar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<CalendarProps<object, object>>'.
  Type 'typeof Calendar' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<CalendarProps<object, object>, any>'.
    Construct signature return types 'Calendar<any, any>' and 'Component<CalendarProps<object, object>, any, any>' are incompatible.
      The types of 'props' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'Readonly<CalendarProps<any, any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<CalendarProps<object, object>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
          Type 'Readonly<CalendarProps<any, any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<CalendarProps<object, object>>'.
            Types of property 'titleAccessor' are incompatible.
              Type 'string | number | symbol | ((event: any) => string) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((event: object) => string) | undefined'.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((event: object) => string) | undefined'.  TS2345

    24 | 
    25 | const { Text } = Typography;
  > 26 | const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar)
       |                                             ^
    27 |
```

Currently, I'm ignoring it with `// @ts-ignore`. But how to actually resolve this?

Here is the link to [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-tserr-nzv2p)

Comment: i believe the type file is outdated or something. Maybe ask the author how to make it work for typescript. The definition is a bit off, but the usage is what's in the documentation. The example is written in version `0.24.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar)
```

The error disappeared on codesandbox when I changed this to the following.
You can customize the defined class by yourself.

```js
    class CalendarEvent {
      title: string;
      allDay: boolean;
      start: Date;
      endDate: Date;
      desc: string;
      resourceId?: string | undefined;
      tooltip?: string | undefined;
    
      constructor(
        _title: string,
        _start: Date,
        _endDate: Date,
        _allDay?: boolean,
        _desc?: string,
        _resourceId?: string
      ) {
        this.title = _title;
        this.allDay = _allDay || false;
        this.start = _start;
        this.endDate = _endDate;
        this.desc = _desc || "";
        this.resourceId = _resourceId;
      }
    }
    
    class CalendarResource {
      title: string;
      id: string;
    
      constructor(id: string, title: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
      }
    }
    
    class MyCalendar extends Calendar<CalendarEvent, CalendarResource> {}
    
    const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop<CalendarEvent, CalendarResource>(
      MyCalendar
    );
```

References:

- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-big-calendar/react-big-calendar-tests.tsx#L143

Comment: thanks a lot... I've finally tested it... it's working...